# AVAssetExportSession AudioMix ignored if I'm using AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avasset, avassetexportsession

I'm trying to **only** modify the video audio via `AVAssetExportSession` `AudioMix` property.

I'm not trimming or doing any other thing except for sound modification. Therefore, I tried using `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` and apply the relevant `AudioMix`, the `AVAssetExportSession` works, but the sound remains the same. If I'm changing the preset to `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` it's much slower but then the audio change works.

Code:

```
let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
exportSession.audioMix = audioMix // ignored

let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
exportSession.audioMix = audioMix // works
```

Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By modifying the `audioMix`, you are not passing through. And there's no single-pass way to say "pass through the video track and decode/apply `audioMix` then re-encode in as `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality`", so you could try a two step method:

Export the audio track by itself [create an `AVMutableComposition` containing only the that track], using `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality`:

```
let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: audioOnlyMutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
exportSession.audioMix = audioMix
```

Then create a new `AVMutableComposition` containing the original video track and your newly created mixed audio track & pass the composition through an `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` `AVAssetExportSession`.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you for your feedback. I know it's a specific niche. I'll try this out now

Comment: Works! :) Small question, after exporting the audio from the video, I need to access the URL and create AVURLAsset with it, and basically, just use it in the merged composition? Or there is a better way?

Comment: That's what I meant. That's how you do it with this answer.

Comment: The cool thing is that I found a bug that on some AVAsset's created from PHAsset that was on iCloud, in a weird state, the old method didn't work at all. And now, with what you proposed it also fixes that haha - and it's faster!

Comment: Small sub-question: Basically now I'm creating "audioTrackContainer" and "videoTrackContainer" and their tracks to the merged compositor. If for some odd reason the time ranges of the video and audio are different, does this affect the composition? DO they must be in the smae length?

Comment: They don't have to be the same length - it will affect the composition, for example you might not have audio for the last n seconds. At least I think that's what `AVAssetExportSession` does in these situations.